# How to get around NVM Checksum error (PXE-E05) to make the ethernet work?

Tags: ethernet

I have Toshiba Portege M400 Tablet PC with Intel 82573L Gigabit Ethernet Controller.
It works fine with Windows, but in Ubuntu it doesn't work!

During startup CMOS shows the following:

```
PXE-E05 error, LAN Adapter configuration not initialized, Boot Agent cannot continue.
```

I figured out that it was due to *NVM Checksum error*, and I tried to flash EEPROM using Intel Boot Utility with no success. Flashing EEPROM always returned the following error:

```
PXE not flashed on port 1, Firmware not present.
```

I restored to Kernel to edit driver files and bypass NVM Checksum error again to lure without any fruitful outcome.

Here are some terminal output:

```
$ lspci -v | grep 82573L
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82573L Gigabit Ethernet Controller

$ ifconfig -a
just listed wlan0 only
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: What version of kernel are you using?
Type this command yo find out:
uname -a

Comment: linux 3.5.0-17 @Moga

Comment: @Danatela I will provide the hardware info that is needed.

Comment: @Touseef don't forget to edit your question with those facts, don't put them into comments.

Comment: @Danatela Here you go, and thank you for your valuable suggestions!

Comment: Exactly how this doesn't work in Ubuntu? The CMOS message is because it tries to boot from the NIC, and is totally irrelevant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally I got the solution. I just skipped the NVM Checksum at Ubuntu startup by editing the device drivers of my Ethernet Controller (82573L gigabit).

Here are the steps:

1. Download latest e1000e drivers from Intel site
2. Decompress the source as follows

   ```
   tar zxvf e1000e-[VERSION].tar.gz
   cd e1000e-[VERSION]/src
   ```
3. Open `netdev.c` and search for the following code and delete it:

   ```
   /* make sure the NVM is good */
   if(e1000_validate_nvm_checksum(hw) < 0)
   {
       dev_err(pci_dev_to_dev(pdev), "The NVM Checksum Is Not Valid\n");
       err = -EIO;
       goto err_eeprom;
   }
   ```
4. Now run these commands:

   ```
   sudo modprobe -r e1000e
   sudo make install
   sudo modprobe e1000e
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```

   This will replace the old drivers and initialize these drivers at startup.

**Note:** The best way to correct the checksum error is to flash the EEPROM, but in my Case EEPROM was corrupted and wouldn't flash. So, I had to skip the Checksum Error Checkup at startup.